# Child visitation

Tags: parents, co-parenting

Should I ask my sons father when does he plan on seeing his son?
After the breakup he decided to move back home to Texas. As of right now we only do Skype. My son is 3 years old and doesn't really understand what Skype is….
He hasn't seen him since he was 1 yrs old.

Should I say? “Do you plan on coming to see your son for Christmas “?
Should I say? “Are you able to come to VA for a weekend to spend time with your son?

Someone mentioned filing for full custody.
Advice please.

Comment: How does your son respond to having a skype call with his father? Is that more towards "Papa! Why can't I hug you?" or more towards "who is that strange man? I don't want to have anything to do with him"? Also, have you previously during or after the breakup talked with your ex about in-person meetings with your son?

Comment: The questions about how to deal with your son's father are good and on-topic, but as they are about dealing with another adult I'm wondering if they might do better over in the Interpersonal Skills SE https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/. Either way, we would need a lot more info about his history and attitudes to advise. As for filing for full custody, that is going to depend hugely on a bunch of circumstances that we can't see; its really something you would have to talk to a lawyer about.

Answer (score 1):

Im a divorced father and my personal reaction to a mother reaching out like this really depends on how you say it.

"Hey! [Sons name] would really appreciate to see you in the lead up to christmas. Would you like to come down for a few days? I can book you an airbnb nearby, or we have a guest room. He would be over the moon to see you."

thats much better than laying the guilt trip in a message like "hey, why dont you want to see your son".

Good luck.